# What does "ACCEPTED" and "CANCELING" states do in the ros2 action state machine?

Tags: ros, ros2, action

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://design.ros2.org/img/actions/goal_state_machine.png

From the [figure](http://design.ros2.org/articles/actions.html) above, when exactly does the used-defined functions (`handle_goal`, `handle_cancel`, and `handle_accepted`) passed to the [`create_server`](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp_action/namespacerclcpp__action.html#aac27305f020b4586d4ae781024ac80e4) function get called?

What I understand from the [document](http://design.ros2.org/articles/actions.html) is that: once we return `rclcpp_action::GoalResponse::ACCEPT_AND_EXECUTE` from the `handle_goal` (passed to  the [`create_server`](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp_action/namespacerclcpp__action.html#aac27305f020b4586d4ae781024ac80e4)), then at some point, the `handle_accepted` function will get called and we can perform the task inside the `handle_accepted` function.

But for cancelling the action, I am a little bit confused reading the document. From the [document](http://design.ros2.org/articles/actions.html), it is written that:

> - **CANCELING** - The client has requested that the goal be canceled and the action server has accepted the cancel request. This state is useful for any **user-defined “clean up”** that the action server may have to do.

But once we return `rclcpp_action::CancelResponse::ACCEPT` in the function `handle_cancel` (passed to the [`create_server`](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp_action/namespacerclcpp__action.html#aac27305f020b4586d4ae781024ac80e4)), what happen and what does the "CANCELING" state in the figure do? Where should we define the user-defined "clean up" function?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372968/what-does-%22accepted%22-and-%22canceling%22-states-do-in-the-ros2-action-state-machine?/) by [wkpst](https://answers.ros.org/users/69647/wkpst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) on 2021-03-01**:
Just a note, please *DO NOT* cross post ROS answers questions to ROS Discourse.

**Comment by [wkpst](https://answers.ros.org/users/69647/wkpst/) on 2021-03-01**:
@kscottz Sorry, I posted on ROS Discourse first and I realized I should post here. Will remove my post on ROS Discourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With respect to the diagram:

- `handle_goal` is called when a goal is received (before ACCEPTED).

If `handle_goal` returns "accept", then the goal state is set to ACCEPTED. The ACCEPTED state tells us (and the action client) that the goal is queued for execution. It's possible that the action server chooses to defer execution (e.g. queue the goal for later), hence we don't always jump straight to EXECUTING. The "ACCEPT_AND_EXECUTE" return code is a convenient shortcut if we want to skip straight to EXECUTING.

- `handle_accepted` is called after a goal enters the ACCEPTED state.

This is a convenient way to let the code know that a particular goal handle *could* be executed. It is up to the action server to explicitly transition the goal to the EXECUTING state.

CANCELING and CANCELED work in a similar way:

- `handle_cancel` is called when a cancel request is received (before CANCELING).

If the cancel request is accepted, then the goal enters in to the CANCELING state.
Note, however, this does not mean the goal has been completely canceled yet. There may be a time delay between entering CANCELING and transitioning to CANCELED. It is up to the action server to explicitly signal that the goal is canceled.

- Calling `canceled()` on the goal handle is the signal to transition the state to CANCELED.

  I.e. `canceled()` indicates that the action server is finished canceling the goal.

Perhaps the [demo code](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/ed0299dc808f94b3c995dd4530680560e07226ff/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_cpp/src/fibonacci_action_server.cpp#L98-L103) makes this more concrete:

```
if (goal_handle->is_canceling()) {
  result->sequence = sequence;
  goal_handle->canceled(result);
  RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Goal canceled");
  return;
}
```

Above, the goal execution thread checks if a cancel request has been accepted (`goal_handle->is_canceling()`), and if so it immediately transitions the goal to CANCELED (`goal_handle->canceled()`). In practice, it's possible the code might do something more complex before calling `goal_handle->canceled()` (e.g. wait for a robot should put down an object it is grasping).

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2021-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wkpst](https://answers.ros.org/users/69647/wkpst/) on 2021-03-01**:
@jacobperron Thanks for your detailed explanation. Aha, so it seems the design is that: the user (server side) is responsible for checking if `goal_handle->is_canceling()` and handle the clean-up task here. Once finished, call `goal_handle->canceled()` in order to transition the `goal_handle` to the terminal state `CANCELED`.

**Comment by [wkpst](https://answers.ros.org/users/69647/wkpst/) on 2021-03-02**:
@jacobperron I'm just curious if I understand correctly that the `handle_cancel` is also a blocking call as well as `handle_accepted` right? Because sometimes if `handle_cancel` (which takes some time before returning `rclcpp_action::CancelResponse::ACCEPT`) returns after `handle_accepted` has finished, I do get this error: `what(): goal_handle attempted invalid transition from state SUCCEEDED with event CANCEL_GOAL`.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2021-03-02**:
It's an implementation detail, but I believe both `handle_cancel` and `handle_accepted` are blocking in both `rclcpp` and `rclpy`. From the error message, it sounds like the action server is marking the goal as done (called `goal_handle->succeeded()`) and then a cancel request is accepted. I don't think you should be seeing this error; it could be a bug in `rclcpp_action`. Consider opening an issue on GitHub with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).